# wsl -e cannot run a script that I can run when wsl has been executed

Tags: scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, execute-command

I created a script in Ubuntu:

```
# bash_test_01.sh
echo "cmd is executed"
```

Running the script from inside WSL works:

```
> wsl
$ cd /home
$ /home/bash_test_01.sh
cmd is executed.
```

However running the script from outside WSL fails:

````
> wsl  -e /home/bash_test_01.sh
WSL (31608) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /home/adm_difolco_e/bash_test_01.sh failed 8```
WSL (31608) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
````

Comment: For *way* more information than you probably ever wanted to know about how this works, see [my Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71112917/11810933) on a similar question.  `-e` is a complicated beast.  Fortunately, the first part of @Rinzwind's answer will work just fine.  And other "inefficiencies" that I cover in the SO answer are likely to be minor :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` needs a command to be followed (can be a "shell" name, like `bash`).

```
 wsl -e bash /home/adm_difolco_e/bash_test_01.sh
```

Either ditch the `-e` and add a she-bang to your shell script or add `bash`.

Alternative: make your script executable (that makes it a command):

```
chmod 700 /home/adm_difolco_e/bash_test_01.sh
wsl -e ./home/adm_difolco_e/bash_test_01.sh
```

Comment: Upvoted for the first part, but doesn't the fact that they were able to execute the script in Bash via `/home/adm_difolco_e/bash_test_01.sh` (from the question) mean that it was already set as executable?  Also, preferably, the `-e` is used *with* the shebang, otherwise technically Bash gets invoked twice.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds unless powershell prepends it -or-  bash is active and on normal wsl 
 it isn;t. I would assume there should be a  "dot" in front of / otherwise, Not 100% sure though ;)

Comment: *"bash is active and on normal wsl it isn't"* - Actually, it is.  Without the `-e`, WSL invokes the default user shell and passes the remaining command-line to it using `-c`.  You can demonstrate this by running `wsl ps` (shows the shell running) vs. `wsl -e ps` (doesn't show the shell running, since `-e` runs the command *without* the shell).

Comment: Oh wait - You won't see Bash, even though it's invoked.  I'm using Fish as my default shell, but Bash does an implicit `exec` with `-c` IIRC, so it's still "hidden" from `ps` even though it ran.  I'll have to "prove" it using another technique, though ;-)